# Using PHP to Get Character Before the First Period?

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out how to get the character before the first period in a domain.

For example, here's the character I'd want to extract and assign to a variable in each of these domains:

```
example.com - e
yahoo.com - o
example.co.uk - e
stackoverflow.com - w
```

Is there any simple way to do that?  The only thing I can think of would be trying to extract all content before the first period and then get the last character from that string.

Comment: @GrumpysaysReinstateMonica that will return all text before the dot. Not only the last character.

Comment: That actually returned the entire string for me.  `$domain = "hello.com";$variable = explode('.', $domain)[0];echo $variable;` echoed "hello.com"

Comment: try `$lastchar = substr(explode('.', $string)[0], -1);` The answer posted is similar but slightly difference, both should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use strpos and substr functions 
strpos - it'll return index of first occurrence of substring
substr - return specific part of string

```php
$domain='example.com';
$lastchar=substr($domain, strpos($domain,'.')-1, 1);
```

Comment: `$lastchar` is just echoing the period with that code :/

Answer (score 0):

Since strings can be accessed by position, get the position minus 1 and access:

```
echo $string[strpos($string, '.') - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$char = substr(explode('.', "example.com", 2)[0], -1);
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/e94lB)